# Object length detection

Tags: sensor

Assume I have a blackbox and I need to measure the length of a stick/wire that's inserted into that box.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

```
           Box
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |        Stick/wire
|                                    |   ------------------------------------------------
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
     Output = 0 cm


  Insert the object through a hole


       Box
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |        Stick/wire
|                             -------+----------------------------------------
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
      Output = 10 cm


       Box
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |        Stick/wire
|                 -------------------+--------------------------------
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
      Output = 20 cm
```

The object inserted can have some properties, if it makes things easier to measure this.

Comment: What's the desired accuracy?

Comment: Let's say in 0.5 cm steps.

Comment: First things that come to my mind would be either with an encoder roll on the entrance point or with optical sensors inside the box that detect whether the object reached a certain point

Comment: I had exactly the same ideas, didn't want to write here to influence original ideas (plus I didn't know there is a thing called roller encoder sensor) The encoder roll on the entrance point sounds better though, given the low accuracy requirement. I would need probably a lot of optical sensors if I go that route. BTW, the object inserted can be as long as 100 cm.

Comment: In the industry such things are called "linear position sensors". Doing a search for "diy linear position sensor" might point you to some creative/unconventional ideas.

Comment: This stick can have a conductive stripe with defined resistivity wrapped along it (that is aligned to the length of it, wrapping around the inserted end), then the box can have contact brushes connected to some kind of resistance meter. This might require the stick to have a certain cross-section shape too to align with the brushes

Answer (score 0):

There are probably 100 ways to do it:

- Gluing small magnets on a stick and use a hall sensor and count
- Make holes on a stick and use a photo barrier and count.
- Attach a rope at the end of the stick, winding it to a spool connected to a multi-turn potentiometer.
- Use a stepper motor to insert the stick with a stop switch at the end and count the steps
- Put QR codes on a tick and use a camera to detect the position relative to the box using AI.